# Prove that a sequence whose second difference is a nonzero constant is quadratic.

Tags: sequences-and-series, quadratics

For example, if {$a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, ...$} is the sequence, 
the first difference is {$a_1-a_0, a_2-a_1, a_3-a_2, ...$}, 
and the second difference is {$(a_2-a_1)-(a_1-a_0), (a_3-a_2)-(a_2-a_1), ...$}.

I think that using facts from up to Calculus, perhaps derivatives, should be enough. I find myself going in circles and don't know how to approach this.

Comment: It would help to define what "second common difference" means for a sequence.

Comment: It may also help to state the context, is this a homework problem? What have you tried?

Comment: You did not provide a definition.  After a web search, it seems that "second difference is constant" _might_ refer to a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ that satisfies $(a_{n+2}-a_{n+1})-(a_{n+1}-a_n) = c$.  This is a simple linear difference equation and has a standard solution that is indeed quadratic regardless of initial conditions for $a_0, a_1$. I suspect this is a homework problem.

Comment: @Michael. He's talking about the Calculus of finite differences.

Comment: @StevenGregory I'm not familiar with the terminology "calculus of finite differences" or "second common difference," so your comment does me no good.  Do you agree with my interpretation above, that he means $(a_{n+2}-a_{n+1})-(a_{n+1}-a_n)=c$?  Or no?

Comment: @Michael Sorry for the late reply. Yes, you have the right interpretation of "second difference." No, this is not a homework problem. I came across it as I was trying to solve an AIME 1994 problem. I knew how to solve it, just didn't know why it works.

Comment: The way I like is the linear system approach:  Guess a particular solution of the form $a_n=bn^2$ and solve for the constant $b$ that works. Then find the solutions to the homogeneous equation.

Comment: @Michael I got $a_n = \frac{d}{2}n^2+(a_1-a_0-\frac{d}{2})n+a_0$, where $d$ is the second difference. Now I just need to prove it satisfies the criteria?

Answer (score 3):

Let $d$ denote the constant second difference. Moreover, let
\begin{align*}
c\equiv&\,a_1-a_0-\frac{d}{2},\\
\end{align*}

> **Claim:** $a_n=(d/2)n^2+cn+a_0$ for all $n\in\{0,1,2\ldots\}$.

*Proof:* The claim is obviously true for $n=0$. For $n=1$, $$\frac{d}{2}\times n^2+cn+a_0=\frac{d}{2}+\left(a_1-a_0-\frac{d}{2}\right)+a_0=a_1.$$
Proceed by induction: suppose that the claim is true for $0,1,\ldots,n$ for some integer $n\geq1$. The task is to prove that it is true for $n+1$. Now: 
\begin{align*}
d=&\,(a_{n+1}-a_n)-(a_n-a_{n-1})=a_{n+1}-2a_n+a_{n-1}\\
=&\,a_{n+1}-2\left[\frac{d}{2}\times n^2+cn+a_0\right]+\left[\frac{d}{2}\times (n-1)^2+c(n-1)+a_0\right],
\end{align*}
where the first equality comes from the definition of $d$, and the third one is due to the induction hypothesis. Now, rearrange for $a_{n+1}$:
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}=&\,d+2\left[\frac{d}{2}\times n^2+cn+a_0\right]-\left[\frac{d}{2}\times (n-1)^2+c(n-1)+a_0\right]\\
=&\,d+dn^2+2cn+2a_0-\frac{d}{2}\times(n^2-2n+1)-c(n-1)-a_0\\
=&\,\underbrace{d}_{\spadesuit}+\underbrace{dn^2}_{\heartsuit}+\underbrace{2cn}_{\clubsuit}+\underbrace{2a_0}_{\diamondsuit}-\underbrace{\frac{d}{2}\times n^2}_{\heartsuit}+\underbrace{dn}_{\star}-\underbrace{\frac{d}{2}}_{\spadesuit}-\underbrace{cn}_{\clubsuit}+\underbrace{c}_{\clubsuit}-\underbrace{a_0}_{\diamondsuit}\\
=&\,\underbrace{\frac{d}{2}}_{\spadesuit}+\underbrace{\frac{d}{2}\times n^2}_{\heartsuit}+\underbrace{c(n+1)}_{\clubsuit}+\underbrace{a_0}_{\diamondsuit}+\underbrace{dn}_{\star}\\
=&\,\frac{d}{2}\times n^2+dn+\frac{d}{2}+c(n+1)+a_0\\
=&\,\frac{d}{2}\times(n+1)^2+c(n+1)+a_0.
\end{align*}
The proof is complete. $\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: For some reason, now I want to go play poker. =)

Comment: Super! Should I use induction to show that if the third difference of a sequence is a nonzero constant, then the sequence is polynomial of 3rd degree? What about proving that if the nth difference of a sequence is a nonzero constant, then the sequence is polynomial of nth degree?

Comment: @VirtualBen I think that would work, but the algebra gets increasingly tedious as the number of degrees grows. Suppose the $k$th difference (where $k\in\mathbb N)$ is constant and you want to show that $$a_n=\sum_{j=0}^k\beta_j n^j\tag{$\clubsuit$}$$ for all integers $n\geq0$, where the $\beta_0,\ldots,\beta_k$ are constants to be found. In general, $\beta_j$ (where $j\in\{0,\ldots,k-1\}$) would depend on $a_0,\ldots,a_j$, and you would need to check that ($\clubsuit$) holds “by hand” for $n\in\{0,\ldots,k-1\}$. Then, for $n\geq k-1$, you could check if the induction goes through for $n+1$.

Comment: @VirtualBen This reminds me of the following fact: Suppose that the function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable $k\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$ times. Then, $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $k$ if and only if the $k$th derivative $f^{(k)}$ is a constant function. Moreover, it is a polynomial of degree _precisely_ $k$ if and only if $f^{(k)}$ is a _non-zero_ constant function.

Comment: This analog to calculus was exactly what I was thinking at first. Except I don't know exactly how the derivative for a function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ translates to a difference of a sequence.